# Add safe HTML inside unsafe string appended with .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

So if I have an unsafe string:
`'<div id='unsafe'></div> unsafe2 <div id='unsafe3'></div>'` which is safely appended (or going to be appended) inside `div` `container` via `div.text(str)`, then how can I safely and efficiently replace middle part of this string - `unsafe2` (or few separate parts in bigger string) with trusted HTML (let's say `inline-block element`), which will be displayed as HTML,

i.e the final display inside `container` must look like this:

```
                          ___
 <div id='unsafe'></div> |___| <div id='unsafe3'></div>
```

**Edit:** Assuming that i know how to find this `unsafe2` inside the string. the question of proper and safe replacement the one which bothers me.

**Edit2:** Here's a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pa7do7w/  type something containing word `doggy`(`Hello doggy, i'm here!`) and hit enter, we will assume that this is unsafe string came from other user's end. In 'chat' field `doggy` will be replaced with colored span `DOGGY`. That is easy to do, as i am using `.html(str)`, with this approach if you will input unsafe string with `<script> alert` for example - it will be trigered, as whole string appended as `html`. I want to append `Hello doggy, i'm here!` via `.text(str)` to 'escape' it, butt still be able to swap doggy to colored `html` as it is now.

**Edit3:** While trying to solve this - updated the fiddle. That how it must look and work: https://jsfiddle.net/5pa7do7w/1/  try to enter `<div></div> hey doggy are you <script> window.alert(hello) </script> good doggy`. BUT i am afraid that now it is possible to break out of js scope with XSS, as I am costantly using unescaped string in code while splitting it, and i am not sure is there vulnerability or not.

Comment: Can you please tell me how could that appended string that bothers you looks like? Or what replacement you want exactly? Only words or html tags also?

Comment: @Redrif Well the string can potentially be anything unsafe possible (it's user generated) and i want to swap specific word in this unsafe string for  inline-block element. Yes HTML tags is the problem, replace only words is pretty straight forward.
How it must look on display you can see in question itself. this ASCII rectangle is inline-block element displayed as HTML, div's on the sides are escaped to plain text unsafe divs. Again i know how to find and replace, i do not know how to make old parts plain text and new part - HTML

Comment: Can you provide some simple jsFiddle providing what you have now so i can fully understand? I think ive got the point but im not 100% sure.

Comment: @Redrif oh, sorry, i suddenly became pretty busy, i will come back with some fiddle later today.

Comment: @Redif added small fiddle, hope it clears things out.