# Append unsafe user generated text with some others html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have some potentially unsafe user generated text that i need to append to my dom, for example:

`var user_text = 'Hello Stackoverflow users, don\'t downvote my post without reading it';`

Next i append it with `$('#element').text(user_text);` to prevent any XSS attack.

Now let's say i want to replace some letters by html elements, for example, to keep this example simple i would like to make all "y" a link.

So after replacing occurrences, i would have something like this:

`var user_text = 'Hello Stackoverflow users, don\'t downvote m<a href="#">y</a> post without reading it';`

Problem is, now i have to append it with `.html()` instead of `.text()` but this will leave a XSS leak and if the user put html in their text it will be executed too.

How can i handle this?
Note: i searched before posting, the [only other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811007/add-safe-html-inside-unsafe-string-appended-with-text) doesn't have an answer

Comment: You would need to split the string around the things you want to turn into a link.  For those things that should remain as text, you will need to append them as text nodes.  And for those that are turned into links, you would append them as normal Elements. Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @Taplar so i would have to add `<span>` for each text nodes and each html nodes, then .text() each part of the text and .html() each part of the html() ? Does their is not another solution?

Comment: No, you don't have to create an Element.  You create a TextNode and append it.  You don't use `text()` or `html()`.  You use `append()`

Comment: didn't know about Textnode, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var user_text = 'Hello Stackoverflow users, don\'t downvote my post without reading it';
var target = document.querySelector('#target');

user_text.split('y').forEach((token, index, array) => {
  // the token is expected to be literal text
  target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(token));
  
  // if it is not on the last token, we need to also add a link
  if (index + 1 < array.length) {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    
    link.href = '#';
    link.innerText = 'y';
    
    target.appendChild(link);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Pure vanilla javascript version of the concept.